# $p$-power torsion points of an abelian variety with supersingular reduction in the cyclotomic extension.

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be an abelian variety on $\mathbb{Q}_p$ with supersingular reduction and $\mathbb{Q}_p(\mu_{p^{\infty}})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ the cyclotomic extension.

Do we have : $A(\mathbb{Q}_p (\mu_{p^{\infty}}))[p^\infty] = 0$ ?

This is true for elliptic curves : Kobayashi, «Iwasawa theory for elliptic curves at supersingular primes» Prop. 8.7 .